# SQLite point check if a point is within a polygon

Tags: sql, sqlite, polygon

In a SQLite database I have rows of latitude and longitude values that represent a polygon on a world map, using a SQL query is it possible to determine whether a provided latitude/longitude value falls within the polygon?

Answer (score 3):

SQLite itself has no such function.

You have to implement this in your code, or extend SQLite with a spatial library like 
[SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/).